# Unexpected EOF and bad handshake

Tags: python, ssl, https, sitemap

I have a function that extracts all the URLs present in a given main URL, but sometimes randomly I get the following error.

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='careers.swiggy.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sitemap.xml (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))
```

Can someone suggest how to handle this?

Comment: Do you have this error always with the same URL or only sometimes with the same URL? If only sometimes then there is likely nothing you can do since it is caused by the server: the server simply closes the connection for some unknown reason, maybe for example because of high load, because it blacklists bots etc.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, It's only sometimes and it's random.

Comment: "How to handle this": Try again.